# Chance of Success Decreases as Time Passes

Tags: probability

**Reason for Asking:**

In a game, I got in a situation such that I had the potential of dying each turn, and that chance increased each turn.

Please forgive me if I make a mistake in my math; I'm not great with probability.

**Question:**

The number of turns that have passed since the zeroth is represented by $t$. On a d20 numbered 1 to 20, on the zeroth turn, I succeed if I roll above a 1. On the first, I succeed if I roll above a 3, and so on until I have to roll above a 19, in which case that chance remains for every turn after.

How many turns am I expected to survive?

**Attempt:**

I can represent the chance of success in a turn as 
$$p(t) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{19-2t}{20},  & t < 10 \\
\frac{1}{20}, & t \geq 10
\end{cases}$$
but I have no idea how to calculate this expected "lifespan", since the probability changes over time. I know that $\prod_{n=0}^{∞}(p(t))$ converges, as the product of the numerator is finite , while the product of the denominator is infinite, and thus the product converges to zero, reinforcing that surviving longer and longer becomes less and less likely as time passes.

This is as far as I got — I have no idea how to calculate an expected result when the probability changes each time. Any help on figuring out the expected "lifespan" is appreciated — and my apologies for any mistakes.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the expected value of a discrete random variable?

Comment: The probability that you live exactly $1$ turn is ${1\over 20}$ the probability that you live exactly $2$ turns is ${19\over20}\cdot{3\over20}$ and so on.  So you will add up $1\cdot{1\over20}+2\cdot{19\over20}\cdot{3\over20}+\cdots$.  Once you get to the point where your probability of survival is ${1\over20}$ you expect to live another ${20\over19}$ turns.

Comment: @kccu You multiply the values with their probabilities, right?

Comment: @saulspatz Ah - I see; I didn’t realize my problem was the same as taking the expected value of a discrete random variable. I’ll work it out and update the question with the answer

Comment: I think you have a typo in that on the first turn you have to roll above a $2$, not a $3$, to survive

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't believe so. The threshold I have to roll above increases by 2 each turn, not 1.

Comment: Then in your equation for $p(t)$ it should be $t \lt 10$ because at turn $10$ you are down to $\frac 1{20}$ success.  Also one of the criteria should account for $t=10$, so one of the signs should accept equals.

Comment: @RossMillikan Understood; I will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected number of turns to survive can be computed by summing the products of the probability to survive $t$ turns and $t$, for $t\geqslant 1$ (I'm starting $t$ at $1$ to avoid confusion). The probability of surviving turn $t$, given that we have survived up to turn $t$, is given by
$$
p(t) = \begin{cases}\frac1{20}(21-2t),& t < 10\\ \frac1{20},& t\geqslant 10, \end{cases}
$$
so the probability of surviving turns $1$ to $t$ is given by
$$
q(t) = \begin{cases}\frac1{20^t}\prod_{i=1}^t(21-2i),& t<10\\  \frac1{20^t}\cdot654729075 ,& t\geqslant 10\end{cases}
$$
(where $654729075 = \prod_{i=1}^9(21-2i)$). Let $T$ denote the total lifetime, then we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[T] &= \sum_{t=1}^\infty t\cdot q(t)\\
&= \sum_{t=1}^9 \frac t{20^t}\prod_{i=1}^t(21-2i) + \sum_{t=10}^\infty \frac t{20^t}\cdot 654729075\\
&= \frac{162653130387}{20480000000} + \frac{263270007}{389120000000}\\
& = \frac{19316704671}{2432000000}\\
&\approx 7.942724.
\end{align}